# python random.shuffle's randomness

Tags: python, random, shuffle

Following is from python website, about

> `random.shuffle(x[, random])`
>
> Shuffle the sequence `x` in place. The optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a random float in `[0.0, 1.0)`; by default, this is the function `random()`.
>
> Note that for even rather small `len(x)`, the total number of permutations of `x` is larger than the period of most random number generators; this implies that most permutations of a long sequence can never be generated.

If I want to repeat getting a random permutation of `['a'..'k']`, it seems shuffle will NOT give me the randomness. Is my understanding right?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximal Length of List to Shuffle with Python random.shuffle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062741/maximal-length-of-list-to-shuffle-with-python-random-shuffle)

Comment: thank you Chris and SilentGhost for the quick & detailed explanation!

Answer (score 6):

[You don't have anything to worry about.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062741/maximal-length-of-list-to-shuffle-with-python-random-shuffle) While under `len(x)` is under 2000, `random.shuffle` should work just fine.

Answer (score 6):

For a sequence of length 11, there are 11! or 39,916,800 (~ 2<sup>25.3</sup>) possible permutations.  For the [Mersienne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) (Python's random algorithm) the period is 2<sup>19937</sup> − 1.  In other words, you'll be fine.