# "Slice" a number into three random numbers

Tags: python, random, numbers, slice

I need to generate a file filled with three "random" values per line (10 lines), but those values sum must equal 15.

The structure is: "INDEX A B C".

Example:

```
1 15 0 0
2 0 15 0
3 0 0 15
4 1 14 0
5 2 13 0
6 3 12 0
7 4 11 0
8 5 10 0
9 6 9 0
10 7 8 0
```

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8574/generating-n-unique-random-numbers-with-a-specific-sum

Comment: By "random" do you actually need any real entropy here (your first three examples seem to argue that you don't, but that could be misleading), or do you just mean "arbitrary, I don't care"?

Comment: That just solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers can by any just use combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations
with open("rand.txt","w") as f:
    combs = [x for x in combinations(range(16),3) if sum(x ) == 15 ][:10]   
    for a,b,c in combs:
        f.write("{} {} {}\n".format(a,b,c))
```

Comment: I think you want `range(16)` there, given his first three rows.

Comment: Also, it's a bit inefficient to throw away 541/560 of the combinations you generate… but I doubt that will matter, and I think the nice simplicity of this code more than makes up for it.

Comment: @abarnert, yes, I changed to 16.  Certainly not  efficient but for what the OP wants it should be fine.

Comment: Also, to the OP: `enumerate` with a `start=1` will give you the "index" to go with the `a, b, c` values. (I don't think that needs to be in the answer; it's not the interesting part of the question he was asking about.)

Comment: That works, but the previous solution seems to better fit my needs. But, thank you!

Comment: I actually had used enumerate  locally but there was just too much going on in the for loop so I left it out of the answer

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid needing to create (or iterate through) the full space of satisfying permutations (which, for large `N` is important), then you *can* solve this problem with sequential sample.

My first approach was to just draw a value uniformly from [0, N], call it `x`. Then draw a value uniformly from [0, N-`x`] and call it y, then set `z = N - x - y`. If you then shuffle these three, you'll get back a reasonable draw from the space of solutions, but it won't be exactly uniform.

As an example, consider where `N=3`. Then the probability of some permutation of (3, 0, 0) is 1/4, even though it is only one out of 10 possible triplets. So this privileges values that contain a high max.

You can perfectly counterbalance this effect by sampling the first value `x` proportionally to how many values will be possible for `y` conditioned on `x`. So for example, if `x` happened to be `N`, then there is only 1 compatible value for `y`, but if `x` is 0, then there are 4 compatible values, namely 0 through 3.

In other words, let `Pr(X=x)` be `(N-x+1)/sum_i(N-i+1)` for `i` from 0 to `N`. Then let `Pr(Y=y | X=x)` be uniform on [0, N-x].

This works out to P(X,Y) = P(Y|X=x) * P(X) = 1/(N-x+1) * [N - x + 1]/sum_i(N-i+1), which is seen to be uniform, 1/sum_i(N-i+1), for each candidate triplet.

Note that `sum(N-i+1 for i in range(0, N+1))` gives the number of different ways to sum 3 non-negative integers to get `N`. I don't know a good proof of this, and would happy if someone adds one to the comments!

Here's a solution that will sample this way:

```
import random
from collections import Counter

def discrete_sample(weights):
    u = random.uniform(0, 1)
    w_t = 0
    for i, w in enumerate(weights):
        w_t += w
        if u <= w_t:
            return i
    return len(weights)-1

def get_weights(N):
    vals = [(N-i+1.0) for i in range(0, N+1)]
    totl = sum(vals)
    return [v/totl for v in vals]

def draw_summing_triplet(N):
    weights = get_weights(N)
    x = discrete_sample(weights)
    y = random.randint(0, N-x)
    triplet = [x, y, N - x - y]
    random.shuffle(triplet)
    return tuple(triplet)
```

Much credit goes to @DSM in the comments for questioning my original answer and providing good feedback.

In this case, we can test out the sampler like this:

```
foo = Counter(draw_summing_triplet(3) for i in range(10**6))
print foo

Counter({(1, 2, 0): 100381, 
         (0, 2, 1): 100250, 
         (1, 1, 1): 100027, 
         (2, 1, 0): 100011, 
         (0, 3, 0): 100002, 
         (3, 0, 0): 99977, 
         (2, 0, 1): 99972,
         (1, 0, 2): 99854, 
         (0, 0, 3): 99782, 
         (0, 1, 2): 99744})
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your argument for uniformity.  The distribution on x is uniform, but that means there's a 1/16 change of getting (15, 0, 0), which is only 1/136 of the sample space.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. You have to add a meta distribution over which component 'x' will be (equally likely to be spot 1, 2, or 3 in the tuple). The property that I am missing is [exchangeability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables), will fix.

Comment: I believe that fixes it (doing a `random.shuffle` on the output, so that each component has an equal chance of getting "first dibs" on the range of values. But please check and comment again. Thank you for checking!

Comment: I don't think that will work for two reasons.  One is shallow -- `random.shuffle` acts in place and returns `None`. :-)  The deeper one is that while this deals with the order issue, it doesn't fix the fact that the *permutations* of (15,0,0) are still likelier to occur.  One way to quickly see the issue is to do something like `Counter(draw_summing_triplet(3) for i in range(10**6))`.

Comment: You're very right. I'm suddenly much more interested in this problem.

Comment: I guess this has more in common with the problem of sampling matrices that have fixed row sums, etc., where once you get into high dimensions you have to go really far with extremely complicated combinatorial arguments used with things like Metropolis-Hastings. That makes the generator-based approach much more likely to be the best general case approach.

Comment: Although, for N large enough, say close to 3000, (or different based on the period of the RNG used), even the generator approach couldn't sample the possibilities. I'm often really surprised by how small things need to be before permutations of them are intractable. 5000 isn't a terribly large number for which you might want to sample from the list of 3000-tuples that can sum to 5000. That actually could happen somewhere in practice. [Here's a link about it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062741/maximal-length-of-list-to-shuffle-with-python-random-shuffle).

Comment: @DSM Don't know if you're still around, but I believe the edits I made demonstrate a correct version with sequential sampling leading to a uniform draw over the sample space.

Comment: Nice!  I'd thought you'd need a number_of_partitions function, but since there are only three elements we don't.  Your `sum(N-i+1 for i in range(0, N+1))` fact I think follows as a property of triangular numbers.

Comment: Yes that's right -- and also yes, generalizing to more than a triplet seems that it would be hard.

Answer (score 0):

This seems straight forward to me and it utilizes the random module.

```
import random

def foo(x):
    a = random.randint(0,x)
    b = random.randint(0,x-a)
    c = x - (a +b)

    return (a,b,c)

for i in range(100):
    print foo(15)
```

Comment: This is identical to my answer, with the addition of the unnecessary `if` statement to check for `x-a == 0`. `random.randint` can take the same value for low and high, like `random.randint(0, 0)`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right the check for zero doesn't add anything.

Comment: I suppose if the implementation of `random.randint` was very inefficient for the `random.randint(0, 0)` case, compared with the cost of doing the `if` comparison, it could be worthwhile. But `random.randint` is smart enough to check if the low bound equals the high bound.

Comment: I must of been thinking about range returning an empty array in the case of range(0).  Oh well.  We got the same basic answer because I was off coding up the answer and testing it.  Saw it on my phone and thought about it.

Comment: Do note, as DSM explained in comments to my answer, that this *doesn't* create a uniform sample over the space of permissible triplets.