# Splitting up a list into different length parts under special condition

Tags: python, algorithm, list, optimization, partitioning

I need an algorithm of dividing different manufacturing parts in to uneven groups. The main condition is that difference between maximum number in the group and all others should be as low as possible. For

example:

if we have list `[1,3,4,11,12,19,20,21]` and we decide that it should be divided in 3 parts it should be divided into `[1,3,4],[11,12],[19,20,21]`. In the same case if we decide to divide it in to 4 we would get :

```
 [1,3,4],[11],[12],[19,20,21].
```

In order to clarify "difference between maximum number in the group and all others" - [1,3,4] = 4 - 1 + 4 - 3 + 4 - 4 = 4,[11] = 11 - 11 = 0 ,[12,19] = 19 - 12 + 19 - 19 = 7 ,[20,21] = 21 -20 + 21 - 21 = 1. Total difference = 12. In the other possible case [1,3,4] = 4 - 1 + 4 - 3 + 4 - 4 = 4,[11,12,19] = 19 - 11 + 19 - 12 + 19 - 19 = 12,[20,21] = 21 - 20 + 21 - 21 = 0. Total difference = 16. This is calculation of over performance. This is due to the fact that larges number (representing for example strength) need to replace smallest number in the group (weakest). Using super strong part would be too expensive or heavy so optimization is needed.

So first I was thinking to slice the list in all possible combinations and then calculate the "difference between maximum number in the group and all others in the group". Then select as a final result the one with smallest minimum difference.

I was wondering if there is some build in function in python or `Spyder` or similar. If I need to write a code could you help me?

I'm trying to work on random list divided in to 10 in order to reapply it in different situations.  `l = sorted(random.sample(range(100), 10)).`

Comment: Can you state what the precise formula is for measuring the "difference between maximum number in the group and all others" quantity that you want to minimize? For example, in your "divide into 4" example, why is that solution correct, instead of, say, `[1,3,4],[11],[12,19],[20,21]`? And also, how do you resolve the problem there are many different solutions for a given set of sub-list lengths. Like in the divide-into-3 example, you could just as easily say `[1,3,4],[11,12,19],[20,21]` -- what differentiates them?

Comment: Depending on what the criterion ends up being, this can be a very complicated problem. For a criterion that doesn't lend itself to an analytical solution, one approach you might take is to use simulated annealing. But for this, you need a mechanism to randomly sample from the space of sets containing integers that add up to give the total length. [As discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518784/slice-a-number-into-three-random-numbers/26519026#26519026), that's not an easy problem in general.

Comment: In order to clarify  "difference between maximum number in the group and all others" - [1,3,4] = 4 - 1 + 4 - 3 + 4 - 4 = 4,[11] = 11 - 11 = 0 ,[12,19] = 19 - 12 + 19 - 19 = 7 ,[20,21] =  21 -20 + 21 - 21 = 1. Total difference = 12.                             In the other possible case [1,3,4] = 4 - 1 + 4 - 3 + 4 - 4 = 4,[11,12,19] = 19 - 11 + 19 - 12 + 19 - 19 = 12,[20,21] = 21 - 20 + 21 - 21 = 0. Total difference = 16. This is calculation of over performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated comments, it sounds like you are looking for the K-Means algorithm, or similar things, that will cluster your list elements into distinct groups based on their distance from proposed centers (this is what your difference calculation is really measuring).

In your criterion, note that it never makes sense to subtract the max of each subgroup from itself, since this is always zero by definition. So really you're looking at the sum of the max minus each element, over all non-max elements (what to do with duplicates is also a question you need to answer). K-Means will do something different (it will look at every point's distance from the average of the points), but in spirit it's the same. You can modify k-means to use your notion of a group score, although I don't really see any benefit to that in terms of the clustering output -- I'd need to see some kind of math proofs about the limiting behavior of the different criteria to be convinced that it matters.

You can achieve this reasonably easily with the `sklearn` and `numpy` modules:

```
from sklearn import cluster as cluster
import numpy as np

km = cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=4)
example_data = np.asarray([1,2,3, 11,12, 20,21,22, 30,35])[:,None]

km.fit(example_data)
```

Then look at `km.labels_`:

```
In [65]: km.labels_
Out[65]: array([0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int32)
```

You can see that this would put together `[1,2,3]`, `[11, 12]`, `[20, 21 , 22]`, `[30, 35]`. Below is some code that actually gets this for you:

```
In [74]: example_data.tolist()[0]
Out[74]: [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 35]

In [75]: [[x for i,x in enumerate(example_data.tolist()[0]) if km.labels_[i] == j] 
          for j in range(km.n_clusters)]

Out[75]: [[1, 2, 3], [20, 21, 22], [30, 35], [11, 12]]
```

But note that this is not perfect: it is an iterative method not guaranteed to converge to any "true" solution, and for bizarre enough input data, you can get bizarre output.

Alternatively, a more basic understanding of what you want is to choose index integers `i[0]` through `i[k]`, such that

```
sub_lists[j] = original_list[i[j]:i[j+1]]
```

with `i[0]=0` and `i[k+1]` understood to mean "everything else in the list." Then define:

```
sub_lens = [len(s) for s in sub_lists]
max_len  = max(sub_lens)
criterion(k, i[0], ..., i[k]) = max(max_len - s_len for s_len in sub_lens)
```

So a solution for you is a tuple of parameters, `(k, i[0], ..., i[k])` and you want the choice that minimized the above expression `criterion`.

A generic solution for this problem is quite complicated. But if you're willing to accept a greedy solution that will be very balanced except for the final sublist, many of [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python) will do.

Comment: I would like to slice it not in the same length of list, but divide the list in given number of groups (eg. 4) and there will be different number of items in the group. Number of items depends on a general criterion which is: The maximum minus each element of the group should be smallest possible. [1,3,4] = 4 - 1 + 4 - 3 + 4 - 4 = 4,[11] = 11 - 11 = 0 ,[12,19] = 19 - 12 + 19 - 19 = 7 ,[20,21] = 21 -20 + 21 - 21 = 1. Total difference = 12.  This is calculation of over performance.

Comment: That is going to be a hard problem. One way to do it is to use the k-means clustering algorithm. Then "classify" each point as belonging to a cluster. You can do this for a range of numbers of clusters and see which gives the best result under your criterion. There's not going to be a simple algorithm for this in general, especially since the number of clusters is variable.

Comment: I made an edit to show how to do it with k-means, using the libraries `sklearn` and `numpy`.

Comment: EMS, that looks promising, could you put an full code in order for my to check by myself km.labels_ and arrays ? I'm using Sypeder, so I should have the numpy and sklearn I think, but I still can't see.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't mention whats the logic behind your slicing for beginning i suggest this function :

```
>>> def slicer(l,n):
...  le=len(l)
...  S=int(np.around(float(le)/n))
...  return [l[i:i+S] for i in range(0,le,S)]
... 
>>> slicer([1,3,4,11,12,19,20,21],2)
[[1, 3, 4, 11], [12, 19, 20, 21]]
>>> slicer([1,3,4,11,12,19,20,21],3)
[[1, 3, 4], [11, 12, 19], [20, 21]]
>>> slicer([1,3,4,11,12,19,20,21],4)
[[1, 3], [4, 11], [12, 19], [20, 21]]
```

Here i use [`numpy.around`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) to round the `float(le)/n` for got a true slicing !

Comment: I would like to slice it in all possible ways and then compare it in order to achieve the result with the minimum differences.                                                                      import random 

screws = sorted(random.sample(range(10), 4))

from itertools import chain, combinations

def subsets(arr):
 
    return chain(*[combinations(arr,i + 1) for i,a in enumerate(arr)])

def k_subset(arr, k):
    s_arr = sorted(arr)
    return list([(i) for i in combinations(subsets(arr),k) 
               if sorted(chain(*i)) == s_arr])
print k_subset(screws,3)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: based on clarified question, here is another algorithm. I still kept the original response below in case it's relevant.**

You can solve the problem using dynamic programming. Note that the code below is not optimized for speed, because I thought that would make it too hard to understand. If you implement it carefully, you can do it in `O(N * K)`, where `N` is the length of `a` and `K` is the number of sets to partition into.

```
a = [1,3,4,11,12,19,20,21]
S = []
K = 3

# memoize results in (len(a) + 1) by K array                                                                                                                             
memo_partitions = [[None for j in xrange(len(a) + 1)] for i in xrange(K + 1)]

def compute_cost(arr):
    # this is the objective to be minimized                                                                                                                              
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return 0
    return sum(arr[-1] - x for x in arr)

def compute_best_partition(k, n):
    # computes the best partition of the first `n` elements of `a`                                                                                                       
    # into `k` parts                                                                                                                                                     
    if n == 0:
        return [[] for _ in xrange(k)], 0
    if k == 1:
        return [a[:n]], compute_cost(a[:n])

    if memo_partitions[k][n] is not None:
        return memo_partitions[k][n]

    best_partition = [[] for _ in xrange(k - 1)] + [a[:n]]
    best_cost = compute_cost(a[:n])
    for i in xrange(1, n):
        last_group = a[i:n]
        additional_cost = compute_cost(last_group)
        partition, cost = compute_best_partition(k - 1, i)

        if cost + additional_cost < best_cost:
            best_partition = partition[:]
            best_partition.append(last_group)
            best_cost = cost + additional_cost

    memo_partitions[k][n] = (best_partition, best_cost)
    return memo_partitions[k][n]

best_partition, cost = compute_best_partition(K, len(a))
print best_partition
```

**Original response below.**

Here are two approaches that might do what you want. Suppose your numbers are, in ascending order,

```
a[0], a[1], ... , a[n - 1]
```

Let `max_diff(S)` denote the maximum difference between two elements of a set `S`. We want to split up the numbers into sets `S[0], ... , S[k - 1]` such that the `max_diff(S[i])` are small.

First, suppose we are trying to minimize the sum of the `max_diff(S[i])`. Notice that the sum of the `max_diff(S[i])` is just `a[n - 1] - a[0]` minus the "gaps" between the `S[i]`. Thus, you can just find the `k - 1` largest of the `a[i + 1] - a[i]` and exclude those. In python code,

```
a = [1,3,4,11,12,19,20,21]
S = []
k = 3

diffs = [(a[i + 1] - a[i], i) for i in xrange(len(a) - 1)]
diffs.sort()
best_cuts = [i for diff, i in diffs[-k:]]
best_cuts.sort()

last_cut = 0
for cut in best_cuts:
    S.append(a[last_cut:cut + 1])
    last_cut = cut + 1
S.append(a[last_cut:])
print S
```

Alternatively, suppose we are trying to minimize the maximum of the `max_diff(S[i])`. Then, we can do a binary search on the achievable value. In code,

```
a = [1,3,4,11,12,19,20,21]
S = []
k = 3

best_partition = None
low, high = 0, max(a)
while low < high:
    mid = (low + high) / 2

    # try to get all max_diffs <= mid                                                                                                                                    
    full_partition = []
    last_set = [a[0]]
    for val in a[1:]:
        if val > last_set[0] + mid:
            full_partition.append(last_set)
            last_set = [val]
        else:
            last_set.append(val)
    full_partition.append(last_set)

    if len(full_partition) > k:
        low = mid + 1
    else:
        high = mid
        best_partition = full_partition

S = best_partition
print S
```

Comment: I was trying to ran your code, but I got 'None' as the answer. Could you show your reply and full code? a = [1,3,4,11,12,19,20,21]
S = []
k = 3
def partition(a,k):

    diffs = [(a[i + 1] - a[i], i) for i in xrange(len(a) - 1)]
    diffs.sort()
    best_cuts = [i for diff, i in diffs[-k:]]
    best_cuts.sort()

    last_cut = 0
    for cut in best_cuts:
        S.append(a[last_cut:cut + 1])
        last_cut = cut + 1
        S.append(a[last_cut:])

print partition(a,k)

Comment: The result is stored in `S`.