# Is `/dev/urandom` suitable for simulation purpose?

Tags: c, linux, unix, random

It seems that using plain C in unix-like systems, `fread` from `/dev/urandom` is the simplest way to extract high quality random bytes. I need to run a simulation that needs about 10k 32-bit random numbers per second, and it may run for several days. Is `/dev/urandom` okay to use for this purpose? How is the quality of random bytes from here when the entropy pool is depleted?

**edit_1**

While I'm now running 3 parallel diehard tests for `/dev/urandom` in my laptop, I got the following interesting lines. The test isn't yet complete.

```
#=============================================================================#
        test_name   |ntup| tsamples |psamples|  p-value |Assessment
#=============================================================================#
 diehard_parking_lot|   0|     12000|     100|0.99573896|   WEAK
        diehard_sums|   0|       100|     100|0.00116464|   WEAK
          sts_serial|   7|    100000|     100|0.99996076|   WEAK
```

Comment: Please don't downvote without any explanation when you personally dislike a question.

Comment: Please narrow down your issue. What kind of distribution do you want? Do you want repeatable sequences? Do you need cryptographically secure random numbers? `/dev/urandom` may be OK for your application (it's a CSPRNG), unless you want repeatable sequences.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I'm now under linux, but it's good to know if some other system has some issues on this. It doesn't need to be cryptographically secure, but I don't want the same random sequence after a cycle of 4294967296, for example.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I'm asking this question because it's hard to search in google about the underlying algorithm that `/dev/urandom` uses, or what exactly happens when the entropy pool is depleted. In other words, how bad can it be?

Comment: Ok, this is clearly too broad. xiver77 doesn't know what are his requirements.

Comment: @xiver77 There are many PRNGs with periods far in excess of 2^32 iterations. For example, the period of the Mersenne Twister is 2^19937-1. I would recommend using [PCG](http://www.pcg-random.org/) with an initial state seeded from /dev/urandom

Comment: @this I know what my requirements are ask me if you're interested.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Was pcg seriously tested( not by the author )? I wouldn't accept a new entry just like that.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage I do know the existence of Mersenne Twister or PCG, and I tested both actually. I found `/dev/urandom` interesting and the results also appear well. I'm asking about whether there may be problems in reading a large number of random numbers for a long time from `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: @this If you see a problem. Explain what that is. It's that simple.

Comment: @that It apparently passes all the current statistical tests. The OP doesn't require cryptographic security, so I don't see any need for additional tests.

Comment: @that Are you trying to tell me that pseudo-random testing is unsuitable for testing the pseudo-randomness of a pseudo-random generator?

Comment: @squeamishossifrage No, I never even suggested that.

Comment: @xiver77: You mention the results from some diehard tests in your posts - are they relevant? Do you need a PRNG that passes all the tests? Please narrow down your question.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I haven't seen any PRNG that passes all of the diehard tests for all possible seeds. You asked is it relevant to this question? Well, I explained enough the purpose of using `/dev/urandom` and also that I don't need cryptographic quality. But I do need a series of numbers that does not have a repeating pattern or poor distribution detected by statistical tests. That's why I'm running the diehard tests and interested in the results.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis As I have said before, I'm interested in the quality of random numbers from `/dev/urandom` even when there aren't much entropy available. I also explained my need. What else further do I need to 'narrow down'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the underlying implementation of `/dev/urandom` is a CSPRNG, the output pool of which has a maximal period of [less than 2^(26∗32) − 1](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/251.pdf), which is then fed into SHA-1 to produce output for `/dev/urandom`. As such, `urandom` can obviously produce the amount of random numbers you want, however it can not offer you reproducible results - you will have to cache the sequence you get yourself.

You do not have to worry about what happens when the entropy pool is estimated to be depleted, `/dev/urandom` will output whatever you request of it. The "theoretical attacks" the urandom(4) man page speaks of are [nonexistent](http://blog.cr.yp.to/20140205-entropy.html). (the "issue" is a huge misunderstanding of what "entropy estimation" is)

Many other PRNGs with large periods exist which reproducible seeding: the Mersenne Twister in [C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/), [xorshift](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/jarniskola/files/abstrakty/linkeova.pdf) PRNGs, etc. You should be able to adapt any PRNG to the distribution which is suitable for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

As to the "quality of random bytes from [`/dev/urandom`] when the entropy pool is depleted", O'Neill (2014) points out that designers of generators for cryptographic purposes do "not have the same concerns about statistical properties (such as uniformity) compared to general-purpose random number generators".

This may explain why the output of `/dev/urandom` fails statistical tests even though the consensus seems to be that the output of `/dev/urandom` is good even after depletion.

If you want to combine the properties of `/dev/urandom` and a standard generator for simulation purposes such as Mersenne Twister, my suggestion would be to exor both data streams. The approaches are sufficiently different that they should not cancel each other out.

Ref: http://www.pcg-random.org/paper.html

Comment: It's also noteworthy that the Linux kernel merges bytes from a hardware random number generator into the `/dev/urandom` output (and the pool) if present. Newer Intel CPUs have one. Test results can therefore hugely depend on the test machine.

Answer (score 1):

No, /dev/random and /dev/urandom are designed for cryptographic applications where you want very high entropy in exchange for speed. They run very slowly compared to a good non-CS PRNG, and so will not give you enough samples for simulation or Monte Carlo integration.

For these, use a fast but good-quality PRNG like XOR-shift+ or Mersenne Twister. You can seed the PRNG with data from /dev/urandom if you don't need repeatability.

Comment: Speed is not the issue. The question asks for 40 KB/s. On my laptop from 2013, urandom outputs 4 MB/s.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not use `/dev/urandom` that intensively, at least according to the documentation [although if you read the comments thread, you will find an argument that the documentation is misleading]:

> The kernel random-number generator is designed to produce a small amount of high-quality seed material to seed  a  cryptographic  pseudo-random number  generator  (CPRNG).   It  is designed for security, not speed, and is poorly suited to generating large amounts of random data.  Users should be very economical in the amount of seed material that they read from /dev/urandom (and  /dev/random);  unnecessarily reading large quantities of data from this device will have a negative impact on other users of the device. *(Source: linux [man 4 random](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html))*

Early (pre 2.6) linux implementations of `/dev/urandom` shared an entropy pool between `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`, but these days the pools used are somewhat independent, and reading from `/dev/urandom` will not affect the availability of `/dev/random`. Other operating systems use different strategies. In FreeBSD, for example, there is only one random device, which only blocks at system startup.

In general, my recommendation is that entropy be considered as a resource and not consumed in large quantities in the absence of a clear need, if for no other reason than to avoid over-frequent and unnecessary system calls, which are relatively expensive.

In any case, for monte carlo simulation where cryptographic randomness is not required, you should be fine with a good PRNG; for independent trials, you should seed the PRNG from a single read of `/dev/urandom`. (Seeding from `time(NULL)` is never a good idea.)

Comment: "doing so will drain your system's entropy" - That is a bogus claim. Please do not confuse people. There is no such issue. After `urandom` is seeded, any and all applications can read those devices without having to worry about anything else.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis In rici's defense, the misconception is present in the official documentation. And it isn't exactly a misconception, it's also a defense against a complete breakdown of all crypto algorithms. But it's still not a reason to use `/dev/random` for anything, including crypto keys.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: OK, fair enough. I haven't looked at the implementation for a long time (decades, even). Nonetheless, the warning on overuse is still part of the Linux documentation (now quoted in the answer), so I stand by the advice if not the overstated explanation. Thanks for pushing me to reinvestigate. (/dev/random will block if overused, as verified by experiment on a reasonably recent linux kernel.)

Comment: The documentation is actually wrong, I refer to [D.J.Bernstein](http://blog.cr.yp.to/20140205-entropy.html). Coincidentally, I'm currently reviewing a proposal for a talk addressing this exact same topic.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: If you are confident that the Linux manpage is wrong, then you should submit a documentation patch. That will undoubtedly reach a lot more people than the 97 readers of this question, not all of whom will work their way down to the comments on this answer, and probably reach more than the audience for your talk. I read the djb article, and it seems to me to be on the side of using a single well-randomized seed and a deterministic (but cryptographically secure) in-process RNG. Thomas Hühn's essay (http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) struck me as more informative, fwiw.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis: To submit a linux manpage patch: https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/patches.html

Comment: The discussion about the manpage has been done in the past, it won't change.

Comment: @michael. Link, please. And the proposed patch which was rejected.

Comment: It is safest to only use features that are both documented and implemented. If one uses undocumented capabilities, one will have to watch for changes.