# Shuffle a list and return a copy

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle

I want to shuffle an array, but all I find was method like `random.shuffle(x)`, from [Best way to randomize a list of strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022141/best-way-to-randomize-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

Can I do something like

```
import random
rectangle = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
# I want something like
# disorderd_rectangle = rectangle.shuffle
```

Now I can only get away with

```
disorderd_rectangle = rectangle
random.shuffle(disorderd_rectangle)
print(disorderd_rectangle)
print(rectangle)
```

But it returns

```
[(1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
[(1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0)]
```

So the `original array` is also changed. How can I just create another shuffled `array` without changing the original one?

Comment: Here are several ways from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17649901/911945

Answer (score 18, accepted):

People here are advising deepcopy, which is surely an overkill. You probably don't mind the objects in your list being same, you just want to shuffle their order. For that, list provides shallow copying directly.

```
rectangle2 = rectangle.copy()
random.shuffle(rectangle2)
```

About your misconception: please read http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html#no_copies

Comment: Upvote only because you called a list a list whereas others are still calling it an array

Comment: LOL. Better for that than for nothing. But seriously, this shows deep misunderstanding of Python's object model. arrays are contiguous in memory, so people will naturally want deepcopy. To us who know how things work, lists are only "skin-deep contiguous", so natural copy is enough.

Answer (score 5):

Use `random.sample` to shuffle a list without changing the original one.

```
from random import sample
rect = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
shuffled_rect = sample(rect, len(rect))
```

The code snippet above is slower but just another way.

Comment: This method works, though the claim about it being faster was untrue in my testing.

`timeit.timeit('random.sample(rect, len(rect))', 'import random; rect = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]')` returned 1.77 seconds, while `timeit.timeit('random.shuffle(rect.copy())', 'import random; rect = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]')` returned 1.06 seconds.  I also tested `sample` vs `shuffle` on a simple `range` and `copy`+`shuffle` was faster there too.  In fact the `sample` times really started to blow up comparatively when the list was small (~10 items) or large (~1 million items)

Answer (score 4):

Use [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) to create a copy of the array, shuffle the copy.

```
c = copy.deepcopy(rectangle)
random.shuffle(c)
```

Comment: So there is nothing like `.shuffle` method?

Comment: [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) shuffles 'the sequence x in place'. If you want to shuffle a copy, make a copy. Just assigning a new name does not create a copy.

Answer (score 4):

Use a slice to make a shallow copy, then shuffle the copy:

```
>>> rect = [(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)]
>>> sh_rect=rect[:]
>>> random.shuffle(sh_rect)
>>> sh_rect
[(0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 0)]
>>> rect
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a copy of the list, by default python only creates pointers to the same object when you write:

```
disorderd_rectangle = rectangle
```

But instead use this or the copy method mentioned by Veky.

```
disorderd_rectangle = rectangle[:]
```

It will make a copy of the list.