# shuffle a given list randomly?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have a list of IPs, I would like to use in one of chef recipe, can someone please suggest how I can generate a random list for a given node. 
for example, if given list is [1,2,3,4]

node 1 should get the order [3,2,1,4]
node 2 should get some other random order [4,2,1,3] etc.

Thanks,
Raju

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shuffle a list and return a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30253198/shuffle-a-list-and-return-a-copy)

Comment: Bear in mind that if you put this in a cookbook and the node is checking into a Chef server every so often, it will reshuffle the list every time the node checks in, unless you explicitly use a guard around resource that will end up using these values. That may or may not matter for use-case, but just tossing it out there.

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```py
from random import shuffle


def get_shuffled_list(orig_lst):
    new_list = orig_lst.copy()
    shuffle(new_list)
    return new_list


orig_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

node1_lst = get_shuffled_list(orig_lst)
node2_lst = get_shuffled_list(orig_lst)

print(node1_lst)
print(node2_lst)
```

Output:

> ```
> [5, 4, 1, 2, 3]
> [1, 4, 5, 2, 3]
> ```

Answer (score 2):

since chef uses ruby, you can use ruby code in your recipes and [shuffling an array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) in ruby is builtin into the ruby core.

```rb
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]           #=> [1, 2, 3]
a.shuffle                 #=> [2, 3, 1]
a                         #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

in chef, you can might want to use [`ruby_block` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html) and use ruby within it or assign the suffled list to a node attribute and reference this node attribute within your recipes.