# How can I pick a random word in from a list in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop, random

Hello I am a learning python and my question is I have some words in a list  I want to randomly select a word using a loop. Every time I run this code below it returns only random single letters like "y n d"

```
import random
import time

randomwords = ["my", "random", "words"]

for x in randomwords:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(random.choice(x))
```

how can I make the code return random order of the words like 
"words" "my" "random"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to randomize a list of strings in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022141/best-way-to-randomize-a-list-of-strings-in-python)

Comment: This method, even when corrected can print the same word twice. You need to shuffle the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.choice(x)` will choose from `x`, and `x` is an individual word from `randomwords`.

If you want to choose from `randomwords`, do it:

```
for x in randomwords:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(random.choice(randomwords))
```

Comment: Thank you this worked out for me and im new to stack overflow my answer was answered fast thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.shuffle` for this:

```
import random
import time

randomwords = ["my", "random", "words"]

for choice in random.shuffle(randomwords):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(choice)
```

The reason why your original code didn't work the way you wanted, is that `x` will be assigned to each of the list elements in turn. So on the first cycle `x = "my"`, and then you print a random character from that string with `random.choice(x)`, which will result in either `m` or `y`.