# Creating lists from list

Tags: python, list, partitioning

Currently I'm working on a personal project... Where I want to randomize teams depending on the amount of people that are going to join. I'm creating a list where I'm adding the users into. And counting the amount of users that are joining. After I need to add users towards new lists. Is there a way to do that in the function groups? Or should I look at it from another direction?

```
def participents():
    users = []
    counter = 0
    while True:
        participent = input('Who is gonna join? ')
        if participent != 'stop':
            users.append(participent)
        elif participent == 'stop':
            break
    for user in users:
        counter +=1

    def groups():
        if counter % 3 == 0:
            ListsNeeded = counter / 3
            IntListsNeeded = int(ListsNeeded)
            print(IntListsNeeded)
            print("It's gonna be trio's")

        else:
            ListsNeeded = counter / 2
            IntListsNeeded = int(ListsNeeded)
            print(IntListsNeeded)
            print("It's gonna be duo's")


    groups()

participents()
```

Comment: You can use `random.choices` from the standard library.

Comment: `for user in users: counter += 1` ? why? `counter == len(users)` ... `elif participent == 'stop': break` ? why?  `else: break`  Use groups() does noting with the users ... you may want to look into `random.shuffle(users)` to randomize the participents in the list and look into [how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks) for splitting it  ... searching SO will in 95% of all beginner cases provide enough input so you can solve it yourself ... so no need to ask at all

Comment: If you have a specific problem make your code shorter : if you are clear about how to ask participents and put them into a list - why bloat your [mre] with 10 lines doing what you know how to do? Simply hardcode a list:  `users_case_1 = ["a","b","c","d","e"]`  (ie % 3 == 2) and `users_case_2 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]`  (ie % 3 == 0) and state your real problem more clearly - this is not a discussion forum so open ended "how to do it better" questions often are ill regarded as they tend to show not much research effort.  What exactly IS your problem btw?

Comment: Btw. randomizing a list has also hundreds of posts, f.e. [best-way-to-randomize-a-list-of-strings-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022141/best-way-to-randomize-a-list-of-strings-in-python) - so essentially both your to-dos (randomizing, partitioning) are solved problems...

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion I would make is to replace this:

```
for user in users:
    counter +=1
```

with just:

```
counter = len(users)
```

And assuming you're on Python 3.8+, another suggestion would be to replace this:

```
users = []
while True:
    participent = input('Who is gonna join? ')
    if participent != 'stop':
        users.append(participent)
    elif participent == 'stop':
        break
```

with this:

```
users = []
while participent := input('Who is gonna join? ') != 'stop':
    users.append(participent)
```